# Covariates in mediation analysis

Tags: mediation, lavaan

I have started working on mediation analysis, but I am still confusing how to deal with covariates. Here are my models (X, predictor; M, mediator; Y, outcome; all are linear regression models).

Path 1: M ~ X + sex + age at death + education

Path 2: Y ~ M + sex + race + SES

Path 3: Y ~ X + M + sex + race + SES

I am planning on using a mediation or lavaan package in r, but I just want to ask whether each path can have different covariates? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can include whichever covariates make the most theoretical sense, and the covariates can differ for different outcome variables (M vs. Y). Notice that there are only 2 regression equations (one for M and one for Y). That is, what you list as "Path 2" is redundant (everything is included in "Path 3").